# Maven: test vs. transitive compile

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I have a compile dependency on jar A which has a compile dependency on B. Furthermore, my tests have a dependency on B.

When I declare a "test" dependency on B, this seems to override the transitive compile dependency on B, so that I cannot compile my project anymore. If I leave out B, everything works, but it feels strange because I use a transitive dependency directly.

What would be a "Maven-like" solution for this?

EXAMPLE:

If I only have

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

then my dependency:list is:

```
commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
```

The tree is:

```
      --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ testcompile ---
      de.continentale.spu:testcompile:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
      \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
         +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
         \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
```

If I use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I get the dependency:list

```
commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:test
```

The tree is:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ testcompile ---
de.continentale.spu:testcompile:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
+- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
|  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
\- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:test
```

So commons-logging changed its scope and is not available any more for compilation.

EDIT2: If I use anything from commons-logging in the src/main/java, then the first version compiles while the second does not. The additional test dependency "hides" the transitive compile dependency.

Comment: ... the problem you describe is not a problem I have. It would help to see some relevant bits from the poms

Comment: I will try to build a minimal example. Do you know the rule that states which scope will "win" if several scopes are found directly and transitively?

Comment: you're describing a problem that likely does not exist but only appears that way because of some other problem. Test scopes have nothing to do with regular compile scopes / dependencies.

Comment: @Gimby I added an example to show my point more properly.

Comment: Post `mvn dependency:tree` for both cases.

Comment: That's actually the expected behaviour. What you declare directly in your POM has precedence over transitive dependencies. Refer to the linked question. Note that compile-time dependencies are available to test classes, so you could just remove that dependency declaration.

Comment: @Tunaki Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: You ask what a solution is, but what is actually your *problem*?

Comment: @lexicore: The problem is that adding test dependencies might break the compilation, i.e. that adding tests with dependencies might lead to a break of a build that worked before. This is exactly what happened to me when I worked on a legacy project.

Comment: @JFMeier But you explicitly set the scope of this dependency to `test` - why wonder that it only works in test scope then? What was your expectation?

Comment: @lexicore My expectation was that every entry in the pom with "test" is just ignored when the src/main/java is compiled.

Answer (score -1):

Have not come across such a situation but if I understood your problem which is the version of dependency B required by your tests and required by dependency A would be different. If the versions are same then you would not have face this issue.

In such case, you could use `Dependency Scope` feature provided by Maven. Let dependency A get the dependency B of its required version and declare a separate dependency B in your pom with a scope `test`. That means its usage will be restricted to tests only. You can know more [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: I gone through the dependency tree which got posted after I post ananswer. I understood that my answer does not solve the issue @JF Meier is facing but then the reason should be given or discussion should happen rather than directly down voting someone's answer which is merely discouraging.